# fetch values from database in php and store in array in js file

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-maps

i am new to js and php. i am using codeigniter hmvc.
i have a js file that displays markers in given radius on google maps, but the marker values(latitude & longitude) are provided in an array within the js file itself. i need to fetch values from database and store in following format in js file. i tried looking for answers, but unable to put it in the required format.i dont know how to use ajax and json either.
also the geolocation part is not working, if anyone can tell me why and how- i would be grateful .thnks a lot in advance. (if anyone marks it as duplicate .. plz provide link in comments.)
here is my code:

map2.js

```
var map = null;
  var radius_circle;
  var markers_on_map = [];
  var geocoder;
  var infowindow;

  //all_locations is just a sample, i need to load these from database in same format
  var all_locations = [
      {type: "RTO River(eventname)", name: "river 1(eventaddress)", lat: 18.53109147547569, lng: 73.8605202502929},
      {type: "KP chowk", name: "square 1", lat: 18.541304420729684, lng: 73.88412368962395},
      {type: "Westline chowk", name: "square 2", lat: 18.539208985720602, lng: 73.90377891728508},
      {type: "Mawpatta inner circle ", name: "circle 1", lat: 18.51581160734747, lng: 73.92665279576408},
      {type: "Phoenix road", name: "road 1", lat: 18.560731744351386, lng: 73.91761911580193}
  ];

  //initialize map on document ready
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.52043, 73.85679); 
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(){
           if(infowindow){
             infowindow.setMap(null);
             infowindow = null;
           }
      });
  });



function showCloseLocations() {
    var i;
    var radius_km = $('#radius_km').val();
    var address = $('#address').val();


    //remove all radii and markers from map before displaying new ones
    if (radius_circle) {
        radius_circle.setMap(null);
        radius_circle = null;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < markers_on_map.length; i++) {
        if (markers_on_map[i]) {
            markers_on_map[i].setMap(null);
            markers_on_map[i] = null;
        }
    }
      //---------

      //----------

    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                    var address_lat_lng = results[0].geometry.location;
                    radius_circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                        center: address_lat_lng,
                        radius: radius_km * 1000,
                        clickable: false,
                        map: map
                    });
                    if (radius_circle) map.fitBounds(radius_circle.getBounds());
                    for (var j = 0; j < all_locations.length; j++) {
                        (function (location) {
                            var marker_lat_lng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng);
                            var distance_from_location = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(address_lat_lng, marker_lat_lng); //distance in meters between your location and the marker
                            if (distance_from_location <= radius_km * 1000) {
                                var new_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: marker_lat_lng,
                                    map: map,
                                    title: location.name
                                });                                     
                                google.maps.event.addListener(new_marker, 'click', function () {
                                    if(infowindow){
             infowindow.setMap(null);
             infowindow = null;
           }
                                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
            { content: '<div style="color:red">'+location.name +'</div>' + " is " + distance_from_location + " meters from my location",
              size: new google.maps.Size(150,50),
              pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)
            , position: marker_lat_lng, map: map});
                                });
                                markers_on_map.push(new_marker);
                            }
                        })(all_locations[j]);
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("No results found while geocoding!");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
  }
```

mymapview11.php

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="<?php echo base_url().'js/map2.js'; ?>">
</script>

<script>
    // get current location with HTML5 geolocation API.
    //not working
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                lat.value  =  position.coords.latitude ;
                lng.value  =  position.coords.longitude;
                info.nodeValue =  position.coords.longitude;
                // set the current position to the map and create info window with (Here Is Your Location) sentense
                infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                infoWindow.setContent('Here Is Your Location.');
                // set this info window in the center of the map
                map.setCenter(pos);
                // draw circle on the map with parameters
                DrowCircle(mapOptions, map, pos, km);

            }, function() {
                // if user block the geolocation API and denied detect his location
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            });
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());

        }
</script>
<script>

$.get("<?php echo base_url().'mapme/map11b.php'; ?>", function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
</script>
<script>
    // get current location with HTML5 geolocation API.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                lat.value  =  position.coords.latitude ;
                lng.value  =  position.coords.longitude;
                info.nodeValue =  position.coords.longitude;
                // set the current position to the map and create info window with (Here Is Your Location) sentense
                infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                infoWindow.setContent('Here Is Your Location.');
                // set this info window in the center of the map
                map.setCenter(pos);
                // draw circle on the map with parameters
                //DrowCircle(mapOptions, map, pos, km);

            }, function() {
                // if user block the geolocation API and denied detect his location
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            });
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());

        }
</script>
</head>

<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
 <input id="address" value="Pune" placeholder="Input Address"/>
 <select id="radius_km">
     <option value=1>1km</option>
     <option value=2>2km</option>
     <option value=5>5km</option>
     <option value=10>10km</option>
     <option value=15>15km</option>
     <option value=20>20km</option>
     <option value=30>30km</option>
     <option value=50>50km</option>
 </select>
 <button onClick="showCloseLocations()" id="showlocationbtn">Show Locations In Radius</button>

    <script>

</script>
 <div id="map_canvas"  style="width:500px; height:300px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

mdl_map.php

```
 <?php

if (!defined(BASEPATH))
    exit(No direct script access allowed);


class Mdl_map extends CI_Model
{


    function getlocation()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('eventstable');
            $this->db->order_by('eventstart','ASC');
            $this->db->where('eventpermission =',1);
            $this->db->where('eventstatus =',1);

            $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();

    }


}
```

Comment: If you want to use PHP to get some data from the server using Javascript you should use AJAX. Did you try that?

Comment: what exactly is the question? Do you want to know how to query the database and generate the array you mentioned?

Comment: @odedta: as i mentioned m new to ajax and js, i dont know how to fetch data via model in codeigniter(hmvc) and access that in map2.js in

Comment: @Rashmy well I don't know how CodeIgniter works because I dislike `MVC` frameworks but to use an AJAX call just look at `Ravi's` answser below.

Comment: **@odedta**: thnks a lot for the response. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to know how to fire an AJAX request to fetch data from server, and make it available in map2.js

Following it the syntax to make an AJAX call with jQuery:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://yourdomain/controller/method/getparamsifany',
        type: 'POST',  // POST/GET Request Method
        data: {key: value, key2: value2},      // An object with data that you want to pass
        success: function (response) {
            // Response callback
            // Code to be executed after receiving the response from AJAX
        }
    });
```

So now in your code, you will do something like this:

```
    var map = null;
    var radius_circle;
    var markers_on_map = [];
    var all_locations = [];
    var geocoder;
    var infowindow;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'request url to a method to fetch required data',  // Make sure you return the result after json_encode($your_db_result)
        type: 'GET',
        data: paramsObj,
        success: function (response) {
            // I am assuming your required data is in response as data
            all_locations = response.data;
            // Initialize and render your map after this otherwise you might have to render the map again because of the changes in all_locations array.
        }
    });
```

If I have misunderstood your question then comment on this answer.

Comment: thnks a lot. m getting ur logic, but could u please tell me what value `paramsObj` holds? and also is the following code correct for controller.php `public function map11()
    {
       
        $locationarray = $this->map_model->getlocation();
         $data['graph_json'] = $locationarray;
         $this->load->view('mymapview11', $data);
        
    }`

Comment: @Rashmy Can you update your question to include `map_model`, and `vardump` of `$locationarray` ?

Comment: @Rashmy From what I understand of your question, paramsObj will have the radius and current location coordinates to filter and fetch required data.

Comment: updated my question. sorry to ask.. but where will i find `vardump` of `$locationarray` ??